# Create PendingIntent for notification without specifying activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-push-notification

Is there any way to create PendingIntent for notification or to show notification from "data" layer.

In that layer I don't have activity class.

So can Intent automatically choose one activity that is marked like "default" or "launcher"?

```
        <activity
            android:name=".feature.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PendingIntent.getBroadcast() :

```
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReceiver.class);
 broadcastIntent.putExtra(Const.NOTIFICATION_ID,"1";
 PendingIntent cancleIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra(Const.NOTIFICATION_ID)) {
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra(Const.NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);

       // do your logic like cancle notification
         NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.cancel(notificationId);

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works but where can I register this receiver if application is not in foreground?

Comment: i thing this broadcast  is going to be triggered whenever  any event happened in you firebase notifications class no matter  whether  your app is in foreground  or in background. Correct  me if i m wrong also let me know if still stuck in something.